# Non-parametric test with several confounding factors

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, confounding

I am pretty new to statistical testing with confounding variables, so please excuse if there will be some gross misunderstandings or basic questions.

I want to test for systematic differences in species abundance ($y$) between several types of environments ($x$).  The way I would usually approach is with a Kruskal-Wallis test. However, these different environments are not all in the same region. So I would like to use the region factor as block ($b$). 
The differences between samples in $y$ and $b$ are subtle, i.e. no obvious clustering can be seen corresponding to $x$ or $b$.

For this I was using now the package [coin](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coin/index.html) for R, that is

```
independence_test(y ~ x | b, ...)
```

From here I have now a few theoretical questions:

1. How do I visualize this? I would prefer a boxplot, but how to include the blocking factor?
2. I would also like to test correlations (spearman) using a block design, what package would you suggest? Again, how does one visualize this (e.g. scatter plot, but with block factor)?
3. I would like to control for a continuous variable ($z$) at later stages. As I understand, this can not be done with "block"ing factor in `coin`? How would I do this correctly?
4. The last stage would be to control for **both** blocking factor b and continous variable z in a Kruskal-Wallis test. How can this be done?

I would be grateful for any help on this topic.